# Align input type range with other elements

Tags: css

Is there more reliable way to align this?

```css
input[type=text] {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the range vertical align to **middle**

```
input[type=range] {
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

```css
input[type=range]{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<input>
<input type="range">
```

Comment: This also works in all browsers as seen on http://caniuse.com/#search=vertical-align

Answer (score 0):

as simple as this.  `vertical-align: middle;`

```css
input[type=range] {
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
<input type="text">
```